# how to know a intransitive verb version of a verb?

Tags: transitivity

I just watched a video* that explaining about transitive and intransitive verbs. it says intransitive verb in japanese usually has different form from transitive verb but it doesnt tell anything how to change a transitive verb or dictionary form into transitive verb form? is there any formula for it (i mean like adding じゃない for negative form of a noun) or we should remember them one by one?

*https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NLy7Yrr8QyE

Comment: Adding じゃない does not make verbs negative.

Comment: I mean noun. Btw it was just example.

Comment: Don't  have skills to write up a full answer but this page looks like a nice start: http://w01.i-next.ne.jp/~g140179870/jita.html